# First exception handling

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to do a very basic code but got an error from  jvm. Someone can help me ? I really can't find any solution :( The error states : cannot find any symbol when is trying to create the bello object.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    try {
      bello ola = new bello();
       ola.ciao(3);
    } catch( BadException se) {

    } finally {

    } // end of try

  class bello {

     void ciao (int i) throws BadException {

     if (i == 5 ) {

        throw new  BadException();

     } // end of if

    }
    }

     class BadException extends Exception {

       public BadException() {

      }
    }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Indent your code. Respect the Java naming conventions. An dpost the exact and complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

Classes declared in methods may only be used after their declaration in the source code. Please note, however, that declaring classes in methods is strongly discouraged. Also, as noted by JB Nizet, please indent your code/respect naming conventions if you want to be able to debug anything, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Did you write everything in this one file?
And you wrote the class-definitions into the main-function?

In Java you have do split up your classes in a separate file.
By the way the convention for classnames is Uppercase in the first letter.

Test.java

```
public class Test{
public static void main (String[] args) {
...
}

}
```

Bello.java

```
class Bello {
...
}
```

BadException.java

```
class BadException extends Exception {
public BadException() {
...
}
}
```

Comment: I d like to use all in one file just at this first stage! WHat about my new code I have just posted ? Thank you!